# Getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatterWrapper.getDisplayString

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

> I have Implemented `Thymeleaf (3.0.11.RELEASE)` into my existing `spring (4.0.0.RELEASE)` project and able to use `th:text` with no issue,
>       but If I try to use `th:field` with `th:object` on form I get following issue in console.

```
**Controller Method** :
here is the Method I am calling to load my html thymeleaf code.

@RequestMapping("/render")
    public ModelAndView input() throws Exception {
        String viewName = "lc/registration-parent";
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(viewName);
        BasicInformation model = model();

        System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
        model.setBranch("31000");
        model.setOperation("Issuance");
        model.setSubProduct("something");
        modelAndView.addObject("sample", 1);
        modelAndView.addObject("basicInfo", model);

        return modelAndView;
    }

**HTML CODE snippet**:
    <FORM method="post" th:action="@{/servlet/DisplayControllerServlet}" th:object="${basicInfo}" name="form1">
        <DIV id="divControls" name="divControls" class="topbar">

          <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=MAN width="20%"  th:text="#{lblBranch}">Branch</TD>
                        <TD class=OPT width="30%"><INPUT th:field="*{branch}"></TD>
                        <TD class=OPT width="30%" colSpan=2><INPUT tabIndex=-1 maxLength=17 type=hidden name=Docummentry_Cedit_Number jQuery1547556695921="4"></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD class=MAN width="20%" th:text="#{lblProductType}">Product</TD>
                        <TD class=OPT width="30%"><INPUT tabIndex=0 onfocus=this.blur();></TD>
                        <TD class=MAN width="20%" th:text="#{lblOperation}">Operation</TD>
                        <TD class=OPT width="30%"><INPUT tabIndex=0 onfocus=this.blur();></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>


**ERROR LOG**
    [26/1/19 14:32:26:795 IST] 00000116 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause spring: org.springframework.web.ut
    il.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1284)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
            at LCDisplayController.handleProcessing(LCDisplayController.java:227)
            at DisplayControllerServlet.doPost(DisplayControllerServlet.java:465)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ValueFormatterWrapper.getDisplayString(ValueFormatterWrapper.java:40)
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor.java:110)
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:179)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
            at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
            at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
            at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260)
            at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:
    256)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169)
            at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104)
            at org.attoparser.HtmlVoidElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlVoidElement.java:92)
            at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
            at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
            at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
            at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
            at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
            at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
            at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
            at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
            at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
            at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
            at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:360)
            at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
            ... 38 more
```

Comment: Could you please post your controller, pojo and view code. Are you using th:field notation correctly?

Comment: POJO :


public class BasicInformation {
 @NotNull
 private String branch;
 private String product;
 private String operation;
 
 
 public String getBranch() {
  return branch;
 }
 
 public void setBranch(String branch) {
  this.branch = branch;
 }
 
 public String getProduct() {
  return product;
 }
 
 public void setProduct(String product) {
  this.product = product;
 }
 
 public String getOperation() {
  return operation;
 }
 
 public void setOperation(String operation) {
  this.operation = operation;
 }
}

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. Sometimes thymeleaf/spring might be broken because of a bad formed html tag (ie. misclosed tags, misuse of " character and etc.) please check that situation. One final thing to try is to change your Pojo field declarations from private to public. It should have nothing to do with this but give it a try